# How to ignore a route with self-hosted ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

I am currently working on a solution where we have a self-hosted ServiceStack layer running, but the problem is that I keep getting errors when I access it from the browser and the browser tries to get the favicon. As far as I can see there is no option of ignoring a specific route when running self-hosted?

I would have imagined something like

```
Routes.Ignore("favicon*")
```

a bit like the

```
Routes.Add<Foo>("/foo")
```

in my AppHost Configure method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike MVC which uses a **Http Module** to process and hijack all requests, ServiceStack is built-on ASP.NET's raw `IHttpHandler` interfaces. This means ServiceStack must handle any request matching the ServiceStack handler path (e.g. `/` or `/api`) by returning an IHttpHandler and isn't able to **Ignore** them like they do in MVC.

You can however **catch** and handle all unhandled requests by registering a handler in `IAppHost.CatchAllHandlers`, e.g:

```
appHost.CatchAllHandlers.Add((httpMethod, pathInfo, filePath) => {
   if (pathInfo.StartsWith("favicon"))
      return new NotFoundHttpHandler();
});
```

Comment: BTW what should it default return since that is needed for the implementation :) some sort of ServiceStackHandler?

Comment: Returning any ASP.NET `IHttpHandler` will do, which will give you retain complete control over the request. Also have your handler implement `IServiceStackHttpHandler` if you also want it to support self-hosts.

Comment: @cyberzed the default return should be null

Comment: The current version 3.9.37 has no change in behavior. There will still be an error logged `ERROR: [::1]:1337 Request not found: /favicon.ico`

Answer (score 5):

In my web.config I like to have something like this

```
<handlers>
    <add verb="*" path="*.*" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" name="files" />
    <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true"/>
</handlers>
```

That way all files with an extension get handled by IIS and means you don't have to go all the way through the aspnet pipeline to server up a 404. It also means you don't log a load of 404s in your servicestack application.

Comment: Man, this is such a sweet solution... will report here if there are any side-effects, but so far it looks perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Just to append to @antonydenyer's answer. His solution seems to work also when combining owin with servicestack3.

`<handlers>
   <add path="auth/*" name="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" type="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpHandler, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
   <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
</handlers>`

Here SS is handling every request except /auth. Auth is mapped to Identityserver3 using owin.