# ServiceStack: how to ignore a route?

Tags: asp.net, servicestack, elmah

I'm trying to get Elmah working with ServiceStack running as the base routing engine.  Is there any way to **ignore** a certain route with ServiceStack, so I could go to '/elmah.axd', or maybe another option I'm missing here?

In Web.config

```
<handlers>
  <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
  <add path="elmah.axd" name="Elmah" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
</handlers>
```

Note: I do already have the log factories configured

```
LogManager.LogFactory = new ElmahLogFactory(new NLogFactory());
```

Comment: This might be a solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269227/how-to-ignore-a-route-with-self-hosted-servicestack

Answer (score 2):

Move the Elmah path above the ServiceStack one in handlers