# How to browse to a directory/file using ServiceStack in IIS?

Tags: c#, servicestack

I have a directory which hosts my web services based on ServiceStack. Inside the directory I have a help folder which has some html pages in it. However when I try browse to those pages, ServiceStack thinks that I am trying to hit a route and gives me "Handler for Request not found".

Is there any way to tell ServiceStack to ignore certain routes? If a route matches a directory present in IIS surely it can't be a service route?

http://www.example.com/exampleservice/metadata <-- fine

http://www.example.com/exampleservice/help/main.html <-- has nothing to do with ServiceStack as it's a directory

Comment: Already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269227/how-to-ignore-a-route-with-self-hosted-servicestack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks to have been nicely implemented in ServiceStack v4. Demis posted about it [here](https://plus.google.com/106787359118990653189/posts/NxHUpV1sg1d).

The Virtual FileSystem is now fully integrated into the rest of ServiceStack, this enables a few interesting things:

- The `Config.WebHostPhysicalPath` sets where you want physical files in ServiceStack to be serve from
- You can now access static files when ServiceStack is mounted at a custom path, e.g. /api/default.html will serve the static file at ~/default.html
- By Default, ServiceStack falls back (i.e when no physical file exists) to looking for Embedded Resource Files inside dlls.
- You can specify the number and precedence of which Assemblies it looks at with `Config.EmbeddedResourceSources` which by default looks at:

  - The assembly that contains your AppHost
  - ServiceStack.dll